# How to know end coordinates of animation in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

I want to know coordinates of root bone in the end of animation in Unity. I tried to put unit with Animator controller programmaticaly to the scene, play animation and execute Update() several times. But coordinates are slightly different from the real.
Is there method to know accurate coordinates in the end of animation?

Upd. This code should work as it should, but it doesnt work accurately:

```
        animator.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        animator.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);            
        animator.Play(_hashName, 0, 0);
        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        duration = stateInfo.length;
        float t = 0;
        float delta = 0.01f;
        while (t < duration)
        {
            animator.Update(delta);
            t += delta;
        }
        Vector3 endCoords = animator.transform.position;
```

Comment: Can you please add some code ?

Comment: Added my code to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the brilliant answer on Unity3d forum.

```
animator.SetTarget(AvatarTarget.Root, 1.0f);
animator.Update(0);
Vector3 position = animator.targetPosition;
```

It works perfectly.